# Sql batch insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure usp_GetValues.

```
EXEC usp_GetValues '123' gives a list of names like :

Names
=======
Joy
Roy
Toy
```

I have another table, where I want to insert record like :

Insert into NewNameTable
Values ('HighSchool', Names, 'true')

Where name list will be coming from the stored procedure execution.

Is there any way to do this bulk insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store name values from executing stored procedure in temporary table and then insert into target table with default values.

```
DECLARE @tempNameTable table(names varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @tempNameTable 
EXEC usp_GetValues '123'

INSERT INTO NewNameTable 
SELECT 'High School',names,'true'
FROM @tempNameTable
```

Comment: THanks..It has to be - `DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(col VARCHAR(50))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable ([Names] NVARCHAR(256))

INSERT INTO #TestTable
EXEC usp_GetValues '123'

Insert into NewNameTable Select ('HighSchool', Names, 'true') from #TestTable
```